# Can I get code from a private GitHub repository using a GET Request?

Tags: javascript, github, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a website and I want to have some simple authentication. I know this isn't the safest method, but I want something quick and simple. Also, there's no sensitive data on the website that needs extremely secure authentication.

Here's the method I want to use:

I have a **private** GitHub repo, where there is a JSON file with a person's credentials in this format:

```json
{
    "admin": {
        "username": "USERNAME_HERE",
        "password": "PASSWORD_HERE",
        "id": 7777
    }
}
```

When a user tries to log in, is there a way a request can get the data from the JSON file?
I tried using *raw.githubusercontent.com* (raw code) but since the repo is private, There's an access token needed at the end of the URL. The access token also expires in some time and a new one is needed.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhttp.response);
       let a = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/json/data.json?token=MY_TOKEN", true);
xhttp.send();
```

This works for some time, but then the token expires and the token is also visible within the source code so that method's a no.

If there is some permanent type of token that I can use, I also need to hide it from the source code.

If I can't do this, then is there any way I could host a file online, and be the only one with access to it, perhaps with a token? And it would be nice if I could get some ideas on how I can hide a token from the source code.

Comment: "If there is some permanent type of token that I can use": yes, they're called "personal access token" but they will be visible in your code so they're definitely a no-no if you need to distribute it. "...is there any way I could host a file online...", no, not really. At the very least you'll need to give a different access token (call it API key, if you wish) to each user (so you won't distribute it in your code and you could revoke it). This could well be a XY problem, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

> I know this isn't the safest method, but I want something quick and simple.

It isn't remotely safe, nor quick, nor simple.

> When a user tries to log in, is there a way a request can get the data from the JSON file?

Use the Github API to read the file (this will require them to authenticate against Github as a user who has permission to read your repository which makes the whole thing awful).

> If I can't do this, then is there any way I could host a file online, and be the only one with access to it, perhaps with a token?

Any kind of server-side authentication system will do that.

> And it would be nice if I could get some ideas on how I can hide a token from the source code.

The only way to do that would be to have the user type the token in (or use a password manager, etc).